# How to add system-wide hotkeys which do not interfere with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

We have some operators which perform some tasks using Firefox.

There is an external program which reads of the data they need to enter, and links it to certain hotkeys.  (e.g. if they need to enter an account balance into a field they say Alt-A and the amount is pasted.  Other keys paste different field.)

However, the problem is that these often interfere with the Firefox or windows hotkeys.  For example:

- Ctrl-[key] is usually some sort of Firefox or system hotkey.
- Alt-[key] causes problems because of side effects like opening the browser menu (File, Edit, etc.)
- Ctrl-Shift and Alt-Shift are often linked to language and keyboard layout switching

Is there a reasonable solution for this?

(Note: Yes, of course, it would be most efficient to fully automate the data entry, but we are not quite there yet and our system is currently semi-automated.)

Note: OS is Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the USA part. Does this secret program create these shortcuts only for itself when it's active, or does it do it system-wide? Can it use other shortcuts (programmable)?

Comment: The shortcuts are systemwide so that they work when Firefox has focus.

Comment: (1) Are the the program's shortcuts programmable as other shortcuts? (2) Does this program modify anything in the file-system?

Comment: no it doesn't modify the filesystem.  I can set the shortcuts to be whatever I want, but I haven't found any set of hotkeys that doesn't interfere with anything

Comment: Using [Sandboxie Plus](https://sandboxie-plus.com/), you could install the program inside its own sandbox, so as not to affect the entire system.